# Getting error when trying to submit my website instant article

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I am getting this error while trying to submit my website URL

> The provided URL is not being accepted because the site has minimal readership, which violates the Instant Article Policies (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/policy/). Please provide a different URL.

I install instant article plugin, kept page ID into it and everything done right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073160/getting-this-error-while-trying-to-claim-url-instant-articles

Comment: I think this article will helpful for you: [https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1809474069346452](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1809474069346452)

Answer (score 0):

Your site need a relevant access to be claimed and so post instant articles.